# Sanitize some translate values but not others

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate, angular-sanitizer

I have a angular-translate *directive* that takes arguments, which are mixed. Some are user-generated, others are HTML that must be compiled (with `translate-compile`).

See [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VxwWW0u288qCzvVDiTuL?p=preview) for a working, greatly simplified example.

When the `translate-sanitize-strategy` is set to "null", nothing is sanitized:

```
 <p translate
 translate-value-amount="<currency data-amount='balance'></currency>"
 translate-value-beneficiary="{{ beneficiary }}"
 translate-sanitize-strategy="null"
 translate-compile="true">PAY_TO</p>
```

This renders *You must pay € 13.37 to john-doe*.

But when a user sets a nickname to `john-<span onmouseover="this.textContent=\'h@ck3d\'">doe</span>`, it will run that and it renders, after mouseover, *You must pay € 13.37 to john-h@ck3d*. Clearly an example of XSS.

When I set the strategy to `sanitizeParameters`, which is also our global setting, the beneficiary is properly sanitized. But so is the `amount`, which I trust (at this point) and which needs to be compiled!

```
<p translate
 translate-value-amount="<currency data-amount='balance'></currency>"
 translate-value-beneficiary="{{ beneficiary }}"
 translate-sanitize-strategy="'sanitizeParameters'"
 translate-compile="true">PAY_TO</p>
```

This renders *You must pay to john-doe*. So the `beneficiary` value is properly sanitized, but so is the value-amount, which I need to remain unsanitized in order for angular to compile it.

I've searched for a solution where I manually sanitize the beneficiary value, with a filter:

```
{{ beneficiary | sanitize }}
```

But this *seems* to require me to write a filter that uses the `ngSanitize` Service; not that hard, but still some work, tests, code for something that I *expect* to be natively available. Somewhere.

I've read through the angular-translate code to find if there is a (hidden) flag or naming convention or so, that allows per-value setting of sanitization, but could not find that. Something like `translate-sanitize-attributes="['foo', 'bar']" or even a`translate-value-amount-astrusted=` or somesuch. But could find nothing that hints at being able to set sanitization-strategies or omission thereof, per-value.

How is this usually achieved in angularjs and angular-translate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
<p translate
 translate-value-amount="<currency data-amount='balance'></currency>"
 translate-value-beneficiary="<span ng-bind='beneficiary'></span>"
 translate-sanitize-strategy="null"
 translate-compile="true">PAY_TO</p>
```